# torBrowser.app file size changes when executing

Tags: configuration

On OSX, I check the file size of torBrowser.app using "Get Info" and see:
114,061,082 bytes (117.8MB on disk)

I execute the file and whilst it is running I see:
112,770,501 bytes (116.8 MB on disk)

After quitting the app I see:
114,054,939 bytes (117.8MB on disc)

I have never seen such a thing before. Can anyone please explain this to me.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Tor Browser stores some information about the Tor network in its installation directory (in your case, inside TorBrowser.app), which it downloads while it is running. That is why the size changes. It is absolutely normal for Tor Browser.